# primefaces 5.1.6 <p:printer> print datable formatting issues

Tags: primefaces, printing, datatable, formatting

Our project recently upgraded from primefaces v4.0.24 to primefaces v5.1.6.

Upon testing there it was found that when the datatable is printed to printer or PDF there were formatting issues. The column headers were not correctly justified especially the one having longer values.
However it fits correctly if I change the layout to landscape. 
I want the data to be correctly justified in portrait mode.

This wasn't the problem with previous version of primefaces.

The page consists of commandlink and datatable. 
When the user clicks on commandlink the id of the datatable is passed to p:printer.

Here is the code

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon-export-print" title="#{webmsg['action.export.print.hint']}">
    <p:printer target="companyTable" />
</h:commandLink>

<p:dataTable id="companyTable" widgetVar="companyTable" var="company" value="#{companies}"
                sortBy="#{company.shortName}" sortOrder="ascending" filterEvent="enter"
                filteredValue="#{companyForm.filteredCompanies}">

    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{appmsg['label.companies']}" />
    </f:facet>

    <p:column sortBy="#{company.shortName}" filterBy="#{company.shortName}"   filterMatchMode="contains" >
        <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputText value="..." />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{company.shortName}" />
    </p:column>
.....
</p:dataTable>
```

The data is either cuttoff or it touches the column border.
If I go to print options and change the default size of paper from A4 to Tabloid, then the data correctly fits within the column.

There should be some way to autofit the data with the default paper size.

Any ideas or clues to fix the formatting issue would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can use css for this. It has [media types](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) so you can tune things for just print devices and leave the screen things untouched. You can also change the ['paper size']there